# Why does a Web Service DataMember's Specified Attribute need to be set for int and Data but not for String

Tags: web-services, wcf, .net-2.0

I have created a web service via WCF. Then I exposed it as a web service to make it usable with a .NET 2.0 application. I created some DataContract with DataMember that could be used for by the exposed OperationContract.

I notice that when I try to create DataClass to be passed in the web service that each DataContract attribute now has a partner "Specified" attribute for each member.

For example:

```
[DataContract]
public class Sales
{

  [DataMember]
  public int InvoiceNo;

...
}
```

When I create an instance of Sales in the web service client. I get attribute named InvoiceNo and InvoiceNoSpecified.

Now here is my question, when the attribute is of type string, I do not need to set the corresponding "Specified" attribute to true, but when the attribute type is a int or DateTime, if I do not set the corresponding "Specified" attribute to true, the value becomes null in the web service host. Is there a way to avoid setting the Specified attribute? Cause I need to call the web service functions in a lot of places in my code. It would really be difficult to keep track of them all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default parameters for the DataMember attribute are:

```
bool EmitDefaultValue (default true)
bool IsRequired (default false)
```

If the property you are exposing is a non-nullable value type you should use:

```
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
public int InvoiceNo;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could read the explanation [here](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/207556.aspx).

Quote from [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx):

> If a schema includes an element that
>   is optional (minOccurs = '0'), or if
>   the schema includes a default value,
>   you have two options. One option is to
>   use
>   System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute
>   to specify the default value, as shown
>   in the following code. Another option
>   is to use a special pattern to create
>   a Boolean field recognized by the
>   XmlSerializer, and to apply the
>   XmlIgnoreAttribute to the field. The
>   pattern is created in the form of
>   propertyNameSpecified. For example, if
>   there is a field named "MyFirstName"
>   you would also create a field named
>   "MyFirstNameSpecified" that instructs
>   the XmlSerializer whether to generate
>   the XML element named "MyFirstName".

The only *acceptable for me* workaround I've come so far is to use XmlSerializer instead of [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) by using [XmlSerializerFormatAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901.aspx).

Comment: I tried to use DefaultValueAttribute for this one. When I use a default value what happens is even if I set the value of the date parameter in the client. Since I did not set the dateSpecified = true anymore, the date value is always the default value.

// code at client
prm.DepositDate = dtp_Deposit.Value.Date;

// code at service
[DefaultValue(typeof(DateTime), "1900/01/01")]
public DepositDate;

Comment: Thank man. I had the same problem with the python soaplib services and .net clients. I always had to set <fiels>Specified to true.

Here is an example how to fix it in Python: @rpc(soap_types.Int(min_occurs = 1), _returns=soap_types.String)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `[DataMember(isRequired=True)]`