# 'Specify' Postfix on Properties of Auto-Generated Classes from Web Reference

Tags: .net, web-services

I need to develop web services in .NET 4.0, so that .NET 2.0 clients can call my services.

When I create auto-generated proxy classes in Visual Studio 2010 using the 'Add Web Reference...' feature, there are extra boolean properties with the 'Specified' appended to the property name.

For example:

```
public long Id { set; get; }
public bool IdSpecified { set; get; }
```

Why are these extra properties added? And is there anything I can do prevent them for being added? Or can I just ignore the completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was already addressed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048112/why-does-a-web-service-datamembers-specified-attribute-need-to-be-set-for-int-an).

Answer (score 1):

I think those properties are just being generated by wsdl.exe or svcutil.exe.  They only exist in your proxy classes, and not your service, correct?  Unless you're concerned about them being used, which I wouldn't be, I wouldn't bother with doing trying to do anything with them.

Comment: Yes, they only exist in the proxy classes. I'm not comfortable just ignoring them, not knowing what they are for.

Comment: Through some experimentation, I found out that if the 'Specified' field is ignored, the default value is false, and the value will not be transmitted.