# attribute of an object getting set to zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I created an object with attribute `competitionId`. In the handler I call a method in the webservice that accepts this object. I placed a breakpoint on the line that calls the method and checked the object, it had this `competitionId` attribute as 21. But it's throwing an error that competitionId cannot be 0.

When i pass the same value via the test client for webservice the values are getting inserted into the DB. Here, all the other attributes are passed correctly except this `competitionId`. The data type of `competitionId` is `int`

Here is the error message

> Database error occured. Please contact administrator for further details.
>     ErrorNumber=547, ErrorSeverity=16, ErrorState=0, ErrorLine=23
>
> ErrorMessage=The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_CCS_VAS_tbl_ProblemStatement_CCS". The conflict occurred in database "DBNAME", table "dbo.CCS_VAS_tbl_Competition", column 'iCompetitionId'.

If I pass the same values through the test client it gets inserted successfully!
Is the object not passed correctly? Is the competitionId getting set to its default value `0`?  I checked the object that is passed and it has some value against `competitionId`.
What could be the problem?

**Additional info:**

There is a field generated in the `Reference.cs`

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()] 
public bool CompetitionIdSpecified
{
    get
    { 
        return this.competitionIdFieldSpecified; 
    }

    set
    { 
        this.competitionIdFieldSpecified = value; 
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("CompetitionIdSpecified"); 
    } 
} 

/// <remarks/>
```

If I comment this in `Reference.cs` its working fine! But I can't follow this method as I have to update reference.cs manually after updating the service everytime and its not maintainable.

Comment: Can you please add listings for your model and the lines that lead to the one that throws exception?

Comment: sure, and the confusing part is if i pass these exact values directly in the web service its working!

Comment: webservice is very generic. could you please show the code that tries to insert to db.

Comment: Are you making it serializable? How are you doing the webservice?

Comment: Sounds like there's a problem with the variable names. Double check that the object you're sending to your webservice has the same attributes and layout as the object the webservice is receiving, down to the casing and punctuation.

Comment: @AD.Net yes i am using data contract and data members

Comment: @NateKerkhofs  Name cant be issue because the class is exported by the webservice itself, its like project.namespaceofservice.classname only

Comment: Please check the question, i have updated some additional info which might help

Comment: @zaitsman The problem is not with webservice, because if i pass the same object directly through the test client for web service its inserting. the issue is that the competition id is set to 0 after checking the `CompetitionIdSpecified` field which i have not defined in my data contract!!

Comment: `XmlIgnoreAttribute` will not serialize this property, that's why you don't get the value. Please check why it's thinking it should be ignored. Do you apply that in your data contract?

Comment: no i havent applied that in data contract. Dont know why this attribute is getting created

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason.

It was generating an attribute called `Specified` which when not set to `true` sets the `CompetitionId` attribute to `0`.

There are two solutions for this

1. Set the `object.Specified=true;` so that the value is not set to `0`
2. Set the `[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]` in the data member so that the Specified attribute is not getting created when you add the `service reference`

I used the second solution and its working fine for me

I found this solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048112/why-does-a-web-service-datamembers-specified-attribute-need-to-be-set-for-int-a)